# Как вывести циклом поля из вкладок

Tags: php, wordpress, циклы

Проблема следующая:
Пытаюсь вывести значения кастомных полей размещенных во вкладках, например: `вкладка 1, вкладка 2, и т.д.`, поля, например: `Заголовок, Описание`, поля во вкладках одинаковые. Кастомные поля я назначаю страницам с помощью плагина `Custom Field Suite` для WordPress. В общем как пытаюсь сделать:

```
$i=0;
$fields = CFS()->get('best_offers'); 
foreach ($fields as $key => $value){
    $i++;
    echo $value['img_offers'+$i];
}
```

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: А что выводит var_dump( $fields ) ?

Comment: 'best_offers' - это название вашего кастомного поля?

Comment: @KAGGDesign `var_dump` выводит ассоциативный массив, там поля `best_offers` нет, я не знаю почему, может из-за того что это вкладка и она туда не передается. Там просто значение всех кастомных полей, мне нужно их как-то к вкладкам привязать.

Comment: @Денис так покажите этот массив.